# Laravel 5.2 - Checking Authorization Abilities in a Multi Auth Application

Tags: php, laravel-5, authorization

Lets say I have the following guards set up and I'm logged in as both a jobseeker and a recruiter. How can I check an authorization ability for a particular logged in user? The default will simply pass in the current logged in user to the policy but which one?

The guards:

```
return [


    'guards' => [
        'jobseeker' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'recruiter' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

     ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

]
```

The policy:

```
protected $policies = [
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
];
```

The action:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    if (Gate::denies('update-post', $post)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    // Update Post...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
public function update($id)
{

    // get the user to authorize
    $user = auth()->guard('recruiter')->user();

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    // option one 
    if (Gate::denies('update-post', [$user, $post])) {
         abort(403);
    }

    // option two  
    if (Gate::forUser($user)->denies('update-post', $post)) {
       abort(403);
    }

    // option 3
    if ($user->cannot('update-post', $post)) {
       abort(403);
    }

    // Update Post...
}
```